# See if 2 seconds have passed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get some code going that should execute every 2 seconds but am running into some issue. This is my code:

```
// lastSpawn has been set to 0 earlier in the scope, outside of this function
var curr_time = parseInt((new Date()).getMilliseconds());
      if (curr_time + 2000 > lastSpawn ) {
        // Do something
        lastSpawn= curr_time;
      }
```

I don;t know if it matter but this rund inside the update() function of a Phaser 3 game.

Comment: Why not using setTimeout??

Comment: just use `setInterval` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Regarding timers/intervals - if this is in a game loop, they may well not be suitable.  @Ruud - this is simple logic mistake - you need to swap your if around a bit - `if (lastSpawn + 2000 < curr_time)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just told that due to me using a game engine (Phaser 3) I can't set timers that way and the following should be used instead:

```
var timer = this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 1500,                // ms
        callback: updateCounter,
        loop: true
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run something every 2 seconds, you can use the `setInterval` function

```js
setInterval(function() {
   // code to excecute
}, 2000) // 2 seconds = 2000 miliseconds
```

For more information about setInterval, look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp